# MacBook Pro won’t charge or boot

Tags: macbook-pro, display, internet-recovery

I have a Late 2013 Retina MacBook Pro.

I recently formatted my hard drive and then it went into Internet recovery mode.

It took a long time for it to download everything after which it reached the screen where it asks for my personal details to set it up. I didn’t set it up and after a few minutes when I tried to use it, nothing happened.

There’s no green or orange light if I connect a charger. Nothing happens if I press the power button - no fan movement, no chime, no display. If I connect the charger after half a day or so, the charger turns green for less than a second and dies.

What is wrong with this computer?

Comment: What’s the battery Loaded or empty?

Comment: Have you checked the charger? Either that one or tried a replacement?

Comment: I’ve tried the charger on a different MacBook Pro and it works. The battery is connected to the computer and during the internet recovery the charger was also connected.

Comment: @FabianGr would you know?

Comment: @SolarMike would you know?

Comment: TBH it sounds like you have trouble with your hardware. I don't know how to help you with that.  have you contacted the AppleSupport yet ?

Comment: @FabianGr I will take to the Service Centre today!